# Agregar fecha actual al crear tabla en Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando crear un evento que se encargara de crear la copia de una tabla a la cual al momento de crearla tiene que agregar la fecha y hora de creación. Este es el código que tengo:

```
SET @fecha = DATE_FORMAT();

SET @Nombre_Tabla = 'tabla_registros_';

Create Table concat(@Nombre_Tabla, @fecha) SELECT * FROM tabla_registros;
```

El resultado del nombre de la tabla es algo como:

```
tabla_registros_2021-01-04
```

El problema es que al ejecutarlo me muestra un error indicando que falta una coma o cerrar un corchete en el CONCAT. ¿Alguien conoce el motivo del error o alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega el mensaje de error que obtienes tal cual aparece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar SQL dinámico, y creo que la función para obtener la fecha actual no es la correcta. Sería algo así:

```
SET @fecha = CURDATE();

SET @Nombre_Tabla = concat('tabla_registros_', REPLACE(@fecha, '-', '_'));

SET @SQLCreate = concat('CREATE TABLE ', @Nombre_Tabla, ' LIKE tabla_registros');
SET @SQLInsert = concat('INSERT ', @Nombre_Tabla, ' SELECT * FROM tabla_registros');

prepare stmt from @SQLCreate;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

prepare stmt from @SQLInsert;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

`create table table_name like table_to_copy` te permite copiar relaciones, índices, etc. Luego copias los datos con `insert table_name SELECT * FROM table_to_copy`

Fuentes:

- [MySQL Copy Table With Examples](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-copy-table-data.aspx/)
- [mysql (5.1) > create table with name from a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489142/mysql-5-1-create-table-with-name-from-a-variable)

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo lo que necesitaba